# Script for adding text to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, product, magento-1.8, checkout, cart

I want to add this text on certain product pages:

Free gift with purchase.

Then I want to add that same text to the cart.

Only for certain products.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create some block and display it product page, cart page then you display that text just in some conditions !

### Product page:

**1) app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/template/text-product/mytext.phtml**

```
<?php $productId = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId(); ?>

<?php if ($productId == '10') : ?> // here the product id that you want to display this text
    <?php echo $this->__('My text for a product id 10'); ?>
   //or
   <div class="my-text">...</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**2) app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('mycustom.product.text'); ?>
```

**3) app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/layout/local.xml**

//add the bellow code before `</default>`

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="mycustom.product.text" template="text-product/mytext.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

### Cart page:

**1) app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/template/text-product/mytext-cart.phtml**

```
<?php
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$productIds = array();
foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();  
}
?>
//if among all the products in cart you find product id: 10, display this text
<?php if(in_array('10', $productIds)): ?> 
    <?php echo $this->__('My text for a product id 10'); ?>
   //or
   <div class="my-text">...</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**2) app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/template/checkout/cart.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('mycustom.cart.text'); ?>
```

**3) app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/layout/local.xml**

//add the bellow code before `</default>`

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="mycustom.cart.text" template="text-product/mytext-cart.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Enjoy